# Show that the projection function is continuous for product spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity, projection

Let X and Y be topological spaces, and let $X\times Y$ be the corresponding product space. Define the projection functions

$$p_X:X\times Y \rightarrow X \mbox{ and } p_Y:X\times Y \rightarrow Y$$

by $p_X(x,y)=x$ and $p_Y(x,y)=y$. Prove that $p_X$ and $p_Y$ are continuous.

So it's clear to me that if $x$ is open in $X$, then $p_X^{-1}(x)=(x,y)$ but I don't understand how we know that $(x,y)$ is open just because $x$ is open. Isn't the basis for a product space $B:=\{U×V∣U⊆X \mbox{ open },V⊆Y \mbox{ open }\}?$ How do we say $(x,y)$ is open in $X\times Y$ without knowing whether $y$ is open in $Y$?

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ points? The words “open” and “closed” apply to sets of points, not to single points (although in some topologies it is possible for singletons to be open, but let’s not get distracted). So your question as stated doesn’t really parse. You need to choose open neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: You should start with an open set in $X$, and show that it's preimage is also open in $X \times Y$. What is open in $X$ comes from the topology on $X$, and what is open in $X \times Y$ comes from the definition of the product topology on a product of topological spaces. If you get the definitions right, this will be easy.

Comment: Well that's part of what's confusing me. The question is copied word for word. It would make more sense if the formatting was more like for some open $U\subset X$ and $V \subset Y$, $p_X(U\times V)=U$ and vice versa. What are they meaning by just using $x$ and $y$ instead notation for an actual set?

Comment: You're to consider the preimage.  The preimage for open U subset X is U×Y.

Comment: Yes, but how do I know that $U\times Y$ is then open without knowing anything about $Y$?

Comment: What is the definition of an open set in $X \times Y$?  If you know that, the answer should be obvious to you

Comment: I gave the basis of the product space in the original question. I understand that an open set in $X \times Y$ is the product of an open set from $X$ and an open set from $Y$. The point I'm trying to make is that, when looking at the preimage of some open set in $X$, how do we know that the set from $Y$ is also open, and therefore its product is open?

Answer (score 3):

For any open set $U\subset X$, the preimage $p_X^{-1}(U)=U\times Y$ is open in $X\times Y$ since $U$ is open in $X$ and $Y$ is open in $Y$ (this is true of any topology on $Y$, just from the definition of a topology).

For any open set $V\subset Y$, the preimage $p_Y^{-1}(V)=X\times V$ is open in $X\times Y$ since $X$ is open in $X$ and $V$ is open in $Y$.

Comment: So what about the case where you have some open $U\subset X$ and closed $C\subset Y$. Then $p_X(U\times C)=U,$ so then wouldn't $p_X^{-1}(U)=(U\times C),$ which would not be an open set?

Comment: You need to show that the preimage of any open set is open. For any open set $U$, the preimage under $p_X$ is $U\times Y$, which is open in $X\times Y$. You don't need to worry about $U\times C$ because that isn't all of the preimage.

Comment: It just clicked. Thank you all so much! I was seeing it as a one-to-one function and thinking the preimage mapped to one specific domain element, when this was incorrect thinking.